# Clear Redux-Form Fields after submitting

Tags: submit, reset, redux-form

Hello and have a nice day,
i'm new to react and redux and in my project we are not using statefull components, just stateless with containers. i have a redux form with four fields. When i submit my form i want the fields to get cleared. I see something about dispatch(reset('myForm'). My question is where i have to put it? In my container and passing it as prop to my component?

My container is like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    submitOrdersTradesSearch: (formSearchOrdersTradesData) => {
      dispatch(searchOrdersTrades(formSearchOrdersTradesData));
    }
  }
);

const OrdersTradesSearchForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'ordersTradesSearchForm',
})(OrdersTradesSearch);

const OrdersTradesSearchContainer =
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(OrdersTradesSearchForm);

export default OrdersTradesSearchContainer;
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [onSubmitSuccess](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-onsubmitsuccess-function-optional-) with [reset](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/#-reset-form-string-).

```
import { reset, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const afterSubmit = (result, dispatch) =>
  dispatch(reset('ordersTradesSearchForm'));

const OrdersTradesSearchForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'ordersTradesSearchForm',
  onSubmitSuccess: afterSubmit,
})(OrdersTradesSearch);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another Way of doing the same thing.
- Redux provides a predefined method to handle submit called **handleFormSubmit**. You can basically do the same thing in that method as well, No need to use an extra method.

```
import React from "react";
import { reset, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class Form extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = (formValues, dispatch) => {
    dispatch(reset("streamsForm")); // string here is the name of the form, check the export default reduxForm below.
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        // Your Form related Fields
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "streamsForm"
})(Form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can just call `props.reset()` on the component which has the `reduxForm` HOC. No extra line of code required.